# Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set", : Unable to retrieve JDBC result set JDBC ERROR: Numeric value 'NA' is not

Tags: sql, r, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am recieving the following error message in R:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set",  : 
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
JDBC ERROR: Numeric value 'NA' is not recognized
```

This R script inserts into a SQL table in a looped fashion.
The script itself is not an issue (thus the omitting of the script itself on this post) - as its a routine script I run every month. However it suddenly gives this error.

Would this be a network, connection, or library issue?

Any insight would be helpful... Appreciate the help as there are no good answers online.

Comment: Does this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Numeric-value-conversion-error) helps?

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you running on? AWS?
Also, what is the size of the result?

Lastly, have you tried using SnowSQL to test this with logging enabled?